# Find the sum of the series: $\cos^3 \alpha +\cos^3 {3\alpha} + \cos^3 {5\alpha}+....+\cos^3 {(2n-1)\alpha}$.

Tags: summation, trigonometric-series, telescopic-series

> **Question**: Find the sum of the series:
>   $$\cos^3 \alpha +\cos^3 {3\alpha} + \cos^3 {5\alpha}+....+\cos^3 {(2n-1)\alpha}$$

*The book from which this question was taken says that the answer is $\frac{3\sin{n\alpha}\cos{n\alpha}}{4\sin\alpha}+\frac{\sin{3n\alpha}\cos{3n\alpha}}{4\sin{3\alpha}}$.*

My attempt to solve this question:
$$\text{Let S be the trigonometric series,}$$
$$\cos {3\theta} = 4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta \implies 4\cos^3 \theta=\cos{3\theta}+3\cos\theta$$
Applying formula on $\cos^3\theta$,..
$$4S = 3\cos\alpha + \cos3\alpha +3\cos3\alpha + \cos9\alpha+...+3\cos{(2n-1)\alpha}+\cos{(6n-3)\alpha}$$
$$4S= 3(\cos \alpha + \cos 3\alpha+\cos5\alpha+...)+(\cos3\alpha + \cos9\alpha+..)$$
Applying the summation of cosine formula,
$$4S= 3\frac{\sin{n\alpha}}{\sin\alpha}\cdot\cos{(\alpha+(n-1)\alpha)}+?$$

So my problem is I don't know how to apply the formula for the second series (denoted by '?') for a fixed number of terms $n$ or should I treat it as a general and separate series.

To clarify my doubt again, what I am asking is that would the $(2n-1)$ affect the formula for the second series (denoted by '?').

*My working here looks most probably correct but if there is any mistake please correct it.*

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Comment: Trigonometric sum $(\cos \alpha + \cos 3\alpha+\cos5\alpha+...)$ is the real part of $e^{i\alpha}+e^{3i\alpha}+e^{5i\alpha}+...=t(1+t^2+t^4+...)$, a geometric sum with $t=e^{i\alpha}$. Similar operation for the other trigonometric sum.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Comment: This is the best question in the whole world

Comment: somebody should answer it, fraud???

Comment: araku baruku araku

Comment: replace α with 3α into the sum you got

Comment: u guys didnt get it?

Comment: this fraud exactly copied my question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sin3\alpha=0$ it's smooth.

But for $\sin3\alpha\neq0$ by the telescopic sum we obtain:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\cos^3(2k-1)\alpha=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n(\cos3(2k-1)\alpha+3\cos(2k-1)\alpha)=$$
$$=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n2\sin3\alpha\cos(6k-3)\alpha}{8\sin3\alpha}+\frac{3\sum\limits_{k=1}^n2\sin\alpha\cos(2k-1)\alpha}{8\sin\alpha}=$$
$$=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\sin6k\alpha-\sin(6k-6)\alpha)}{8\sin3\alpha}+\frac{3\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\sin2k\alpha-\sin(2k-2)\alpha)}{8\sin\alpha}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin6n\alpha}{8\sin3\alpha}+\frac{3\sin2n\alpha}{8\sin\alpha}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove by induction that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\cos((2i-1)\alpha)^3=\frac{1}{8} \left(-\csc (3) \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} (-12
   n-\pi )\right)-3 \csc (1) \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} (-4
   n-\pi )\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Just take $\beta = 3\alpha$ in the 2nd part, and apply the same formula as in the first part.